# Add a class to **this** elements child

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do you add a class to **this** elements child.

I want to add a class to add a different background color to all Compliantitems

e.g.

```
<div class="tab">
    <tr><td class="compliance">Compliant</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="compliance">Non-compliant</td></tr>
</div>




$(".tab td:contains('Compliant')").each(function () {
    $(this, .compliance).addClass( "success" );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this:

```
$(".tab td:contains('Compliant')").addClass("success");
```

Or as you are looping through all the tds then only `$(this)` would work:

```
$(this).addClass("success");
```

---

As suresh added in comments if you have to target specific tds then use this way:

```
$(".tab td.compliance:contains('Compliant')").addClass("success");
```

Comment: This will update all the tds with that text. OP wants only td's tohse who has class `compliance`

Comment: I used only this and it does work, but I only want that cell to change color, so I will try your first suggestion. Thanks

Comment: @morne If you do not have restriction on class, this works good.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ yes you are right but as question suggested i answered it yet i guess you are also pointing to do it correctly. just updated as per your suggestion.

Comment: @Jai It's covering both the cases now (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Use `hasClass`.

```
$(".tab td:contains('Compliant')").each(function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass("compliance")){
    $(this).addClass( "success" );
  }
});
```